# Adding GData Objective-C Client library to xcode4.5 working examples

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, gdata, icalendar

Where ever i download files on gdata .i'm getting  **" #import gdata.h "** is missing in my files even after i replaced it with some new data files from other library by deleting the existing one in our current example.

Currently i am working on Calendar to sync the events directly to google calendar using data.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary and add the header files to your project?

Comment: Yes rmaddy ,still I'm not getting it .dnt know y ..!!!!!do you have any working example ..??

Comment: Finally i got this one successfully..frnds plz follow the below link      http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/

Comment: Note that the XML-based GData API for Google Calendar has been replaced by a JSON API.  See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/